# Spark: How to include null rows in lateral view explode

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table as below:

```
user_id email
u1      e1, e2
u2      null
```

My goal is to convert this into the following format:

```
user_id email
u1      e1
u1      e2
u2      null
```

HIVE sql: select *  FROM table LATERAL VIEW explode (  split (  email  ,','  ) ) email AS email_id

When above query is executed in hive I am getting the nulls however when the same is ran in spark-sql I am not getting nulls, this question and scenario has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715815/hive-how-to-include-null-rows-in-lateral-view-explode)

Spark `sql`:

1. `select *  FROM table LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode (  split (  email  ,','  ) ) email AS email_id;`
2. `select * from table lateral view POSEXPLODE_OUTER(split(email,',')) email as email_id <br>`

The second is failing with syntax issue, I tried searching for lateral view with posexplode_outer but could not get much results, I want to bring nulls in spark-sql.

Comment: what's the problem with the first query in spark sql? the second function `posexplode_outer` isn't valid.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala: Even after running first query i am not able to see NULLs in result, "SELECT POSEXPLODE_OUTER(array(10,20)) AS (POS,SO);" this runs in spark-sql

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739072/spark-sql-how-to-explode-without-losing-null-values

Comment: @sramalingam24: Yea I had checked this earlier but it was wrt dataframe, i needed to implement in spark-sql query

Comment: Everything you write in spark SQL is available as dataframe function so going from one to the other is just semantics

Comment: @Vinod What is wrong with using `explode_outer` as suggested in the answer? It will keep null values.

Comment: @Shaido: Nothing wrong just that if it gives the POS also it will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Spark SQL doesn't use HiveQL. It is partially compatible with it, but shouldn't be mistaken. Instead of using `LATERAL VIEW` you should just use `SELECT`

```scala
Seq(
  ("u1", "e1, e2"), ("u2", null)
).toDF("user_id", "email").createOrReplaceTempView("table")

spark.sql(
    "SELECT user_id, explode_outer(split(email, ',')) FROM table"
).show
// +-------+----+                               
// |user_id| col|
// +-------+----+
// |     u1|  e1|
// |     u1|  e2|
// |     u2|null|
// +-------+----+
```

Comment: can this be extended for below hiveql: "select * from table
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(split(ORDER_NUMBER,',')) NOS AS pos,ORDER_NUMBER_SPLIT?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `coalesce` after split seems to be working

```
with tmp_table as ( 
  select 'u1' as user, 'e1,e2' as email 
  union all 
  select 'u2' as user, NULL as email
)
select * FROM tmp_table 
LATERAL VIEW explode ( coalesce(split ( email ,',' ), array(NULL)) ) email AS email_id;
```

output

```
u1  e1,e2   e1
u1  e1,e2   e2
u2  NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

LATERAL VIEW OUTER was added in Spark 2.2.0

e.g.

`scala> spark.sql(
     |     "select * FROM table LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode ( split ( email ,',' ) ) email AS email_id"
     | ).show
+-------+------+--------+

|user_id| email|email_id|
+-------+------+--------+
|     u1|e1, e2|      e1|
|     u1|e1, e2|      e2|
|     u2|  null|    null|
+-------+------+--------+`